# WPF アプリでウィンドウのタイトル文字色を変更したい

Tags: c#, wpf

Windows 7 上の Visual Studio 2010 Professional with MSDN で開発をしております。

WPFアプリケーションのメインウィンドウに表示されるタイトルの文字色を変更したいのですが、背景色を変更する方法しか見つかりませんでした。

何か方法はありますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

---

**参考:** WPF アプリにおける各部の名称

[image: WPF名称]

<sub>(出典: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC24017.png))</sub>

Comment: OSや利用者の設定したデスクトップテーマに沿って配色されるものですから、それらを無視して特定の色にすべきではないと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Window`のタイトル色を直接指定することは出来なかったと思います。

間接的な手段としては、`WindowStyle`や[WindowChrome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome)を変更して`Window`全体のデザインを変更することができます。
このようなライブラリとしては[WPF customizable window](https://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/)などがありますので、それらを利用するのが手軽ではないでしょうか。